# How long before iAds become active and reports appear in iTunes Connect iAd Network?

Tags: app-store-connect, iad

When first releasing a new iPhone (iOS) app with iAds ("Ready for Sale" and appearing in iTunes already), how long does it take before iTunes Connect iAd Network will display ads as active?  (assuming that everything is configured correctly).  (I have been waiting for 2+ days now.)

In iTunes Connect iAd Network, the app appears "Testing: This app is receiving test ads. This app's status is not yet Ready For Sale. You have not configured ad preferences for this app."

What can am iAd newbie expect to see and experience from this process?  (I was unable to find any Apple documentation to indicate how long the process will take.)  Please provide any advice.

Answer (score 3):

I contacted Apple. Here's what they said:

> Your app version [new version] is currently under review and you enabled the app for iAd after [the prior version] was Ready for Sale.  Your app name and other information will display the pending status until your app has been approved and Ready for Sale.  This is also when your app will be eligible to receive paid ads from the iAd Network.